# NuxtJS v3 + mollie.com payments integration error

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, mollie

I am trying to integrate [mollie.com](https://www.mollie.com) into my nuxtjs3 application. The goal is to fill button targets with checkout urls for specific products.

Therefore I integrated @mollie/api-client intro to my nuxt v3.0.0 app. Within a subpage i load the script and try to generate a checkoutUrl

```js
import createMollieClient from "@mollie/api-client";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Product",
  async setup() {
    const mollieClient = createMollieClient({
      apiKey: "test_WpjrT**********JTV8j4zDy",
    });
    const payment = await mollieClient.payments.create({
      amount: {
        value: "10.00",
        currency: "EUR",
      },
      description: "My first API payment",
      redirectUrl: "https://url.com/order/123456",
      webhookUrl: "https://url.com/webhook",
    });

    return {
      redUrl: payment.getCheckoutUrl(),
    };
  },
```

but I get the following error:

> 500 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'custom')
> at http://localhost:4444/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/@mollie_api-client.js?v=dff22e71:2077:24

I have no clue what is going on here. Does anyone else tried this or has an idea how to get to the origin of this error?

Comment: The package is maybe not meant to be run on the client or maybe the server (is it isomorphic)?

Comment: You should run this in server route/api